# View not refreshed when .onAppear runs SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have some code inside `.onAppear` and it runs, the problem is that I have to go to another view on the menu and then come back for the UI view to refresh. The code is kind of lengthy, but the main components are below, where mealData comes from CoreData and has some objects:

**Go to the updated comment at the bottom for a simpler code example**

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 2) {
                    ForEach(mealData, id: \.self) { meal in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) { ... }
                        .onAppear {

                            // If not first button and count < total amt of objects
                            if((self.settingsData.count != 0) && (self.settingsData.count < self.mealData.count)){
                                let updateSettings = Settings(context: self.managedObjectContext)

                                // If will_eat time isn't nill and it's time is overdue and meal status isn't done
                                if ((meal.will_eat != nil) && (IsItOverDue(date: meal.will_eat!) == true) && (meal.status! != "done")){
                                    self.mealData[self.settingsData.count].status = "overdue"

                                    print(self.mealData[self.settingsData.count])

                                        if(self.settingsData.count != self.mealData.count-1) {
                                            // "Breakfast": "done" = active - Add active to next meal
                                            self.mealData[self.settingsData.count+1].status = "active"
                                        }

                                        updateSettings.count += 1

                                    if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
                                        // Save the context whenever is appropriate
                                        do {
                                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                                        } catch let error as NSError {
                                            print("Error loading: \(error.localizedDescription), \(error.userInfo)")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
```

Most likely since the UI is not refreshing automatically I'm doing something wrong, but what?

**UPDATE:**

I made a little example replicating what's going on, if you run it, and click on `set future date`, and wit 5 seconds, you'll see that the box hasn't changed color, after that, click on `Go to view 2` and go back to view 1 and you'll see how the box color changes... that's what's happening above too:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var past = Date()
@State var futuredate = Date()


var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView())
            { Text("Go to view 2") }

            Button("set future date") {
                self.futuredate = self.past.addingTimeInterval(5)
            }

            VStack {
                if (past < futuredate) {
                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Text("")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                } else {
                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Text("")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.past = Date()
        }
    }
}

}


struct DetailView: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding

var body: some View {
   Text("View 2")
}
}
```

Comment: Can you move `onAppear`  to `ScrollView` s end

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. I also have another .onAppear 2 blocks before to load some data for the first time and the same is happening @EnesKaraosman

Comment: @EnesKaraosman I updated the code below to something simpler at the bottom

Comment: Second code snapshot behaves as it should. What would you expected instead?

Comment: @Asperi I was expecting that whenever the condition becomes true, the color changes on the home view without me having to go to another view and come back, how would it be then so the button changes color by itself once the condition changes?

Comment: Date() is not a Timer... it is just a one-shot current date model. Use timer if you need active time tracking.

Comment: @Asperi how would you update the view once the timer reaches 0? Take into account that the user may close the app or minimize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that all you put in `body{...}` is just an instruction how to display this view. In runtime system creates this View using `body` closure, gets it in memory like picture and pin this picture to struct with all the stored properties you define in it. `Body` is not a stored property. Its only instruction how to create that picture.

In your code, there goes `ini`t first. You didn't write it but it runs and sets all the structs property to default values `= Date()`. After that runs `.onAppear` closure which changes `past` value. And only then system runs `body` closure to make an image to display with new `past` value. And that's all. It is not recreating itself every second. You need to trigger it to check if the condition `past < futuredate` changed.

When you go to another view and back you do exactly that - force system to recreate view and that's why it checks condition again.

If you want View to change automatically after some fixed time spend, use

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(2)) {
    //change @State variable to force View to update
}
```

for more complex cases you can use Timer like this:

```
class MyTimer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentTimePublisher: Timer.TimerPublisher
    var cancellable: Cancellable?
    let interval: Double
    var isOn: Bool{
        get{if self.cancellable == nil{
                return false
            }else{
                return true
            }
        }
        set{if newValue == false{
                self.stop()
            }else{
                self.start()
            }
        }
    }

    init(interval: Double, autoStart: Bool = true) {
        self.interval = interval
        let publisher = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: interval, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
        self.currentTimePublisher = publisher
        if autoStart{
            self.start()
        }
    }
    func start(){
        if self.cancellable == nil{
            self.currentTimePublisher = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: self.interval, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
            self.cancellable = self.currentTimePublisher.connect()
        }else{
            print("timer is already started")
        }
    }
    func stop(){
        if self.cancellable != nil{
            self.cancellable!.cancel()
            self.cancellable = nil
        }else{
            print("timer is not started (tried to stop)")
        }
    }
    deinit {
        if self.cancellable != nil{
            self.cancellable!.cancel()
            self.cancellable = nil
        }
    }
}
struct TimerView: View {
    @State var counter: Double
    let timerStep: Double
    @ObservedObject var timer: TypeTimer
    init(timerStep: Double = 0.1, counter: Double = 10.0){
        self.timerStep = timerStep
        self._counter = State<Double>(initialValue: counter)
        self.timer = MyTimer(interval: timerStep, autoStart: false)
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(counter)")
            .onReceive(timer.currentTimePublisher) {newTime in
                print(newTime.description)
                if self.counter > self.timerStep {
                    self.counter -=  self.timerStep
                }else{
                    self.timer.stop()
                }
            }
        .onTapGesture {
            if self.timer.isOn {
                self.timer.stop()
            }else{
                self.timer.start()
            }
         }
    }
}
```

See the idea? You start timer and it will force `View` to update by sending notification with the `Publisher`. View gets that notifications with `.onReceive` and changes `@State` variable `counter` and that cause View to update itself. You need to do something like that.